# How to compare a variable to two values, by using OR condition in robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I want to compare ${accountNumChk} should be equal 6 or 7 .

```
should be equal as strings      ${accountNumChk}    6
```

Anyone answer please .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This can't be done with `Should be equal`. You can use a workaround with [Should Be True](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Should%20Be%20True):

```
Should Be True     '${accountNumChk}'=='6' or '${accountNumChk}'=='7'
```

Note that `or` should be lowercase.

Comment: Thanks you . let me try it .

Answer (score 1):

@Psytho's solution is good (and probably optimal); for the sake of having alternatives, here's one with only the standard keywords:

```
${check1}=    Run Keyword And Return Status    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${accountNumChk}    6
Run Keyword If     not ${check1}    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${accountNumChk}    7
```

`Run Keyword And Return Status` returns boolean `True` or `False` depending if the enclosed keyword succeeded or failed. `Run Keyword If` executes the enclosed keyword only if its check evaluates to `True`.

Comment: Ehm, what's non-standard in "should be true"?

Comment: in this sitsuation i choose use "should be true" `run keyword if   '${acc_type}'=='Master'
      ...    should be equal as strings    ${accountNumChk}    3
      ...    ELSE IF   '${acc_type}'=='Sub Master'
      ...    Should Be True     '${accountNumChk}'=='6' or '${accountNumChk}'=='7'`

Comment: There you go @SidaraKEO, nice combo.

Comment: Both answer are correct . Anyways thanks both of you

Comment: Nothing @psytho. The python evaluation on the condition, with the encapsulation of the variables values by `'` quotes, and boolean operands `==` and `or` is, well, python-ish. Robotframework's standard approach and general layout is a bit easier for the just stating-users, not pushing them into actual coding.